# Service start while dependency stopped

Tags: windows, windows-services, dependencies

I have installed an application as a service and set the "DependOnService" to be dependent on MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS. In the Properties -> Dependencies tab of my service, "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" is listed as "This service depends on the following system components:". All seems fine. However, if I stop the SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) service and start my service, it starts up just fine (except that it can't reach the database).

I expected my service to either a) not start because SQL Server is not running, or b) cause SQL Server to start up so that my service could start. But SQL Server is still not running and my service is.

Am I misinterpreting the meaning of dependencies on services and mis-reading the documentation? I tried setting the ErrorControl value as high as x03 and it still starts up. Any explanation, ideas or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Did MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS start when you started your service? The behavior I see when I add dependencies is that the service my service depends on will attempt to be started first (e.g. MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS). I'm wondering if there isn't enough time from SQLEXPRESS being 'started', and being able to accept connections, before your service is started? If your service is started right on the heels of SQLEXPRESS, then it could error connecting on service start. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't hack the registry! If you want a service to depend on another service, ask the service manager to set the dependency. For example:

```
sc config MyService depend= MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
```

Comment: A good suggestion which I guess not surprisingly fixed the problem. Although what ever additional work it is doing is hidden somewhere else, not in the registry for my service or SQL Server.

Comment: Would have loved to find out what other metadata is stored in Windows to set service dependencies, beside the registry entry. Yet this fixed my problem too, so +1.

Comment: @Mär There is no other metadata. The service control manager caches the registry values, which is why you need to use the documented APIs to manipulate service entries while Windows is running.

Comment: @Neil Isn't the cached registry the "other metadata" in this case? Anyway, the specific problem I was dealing with came from registry entries produced by an NSIS script. Glad to see it solved.